# Spiraling through a 2d array (l-r, down, r-l, down, l-r, ...)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a board for snakes and ladders, so far I've got the board printed out in descending order. However, I need the board to be printed out the proper way.

**EDIT:** "Spiraling down" means

```
100...91
81...90
80...71
...
```

This is my code:

```
public class PrintGrid
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        final int Rows=10;
        final int columns=10;
        int position =100;

        int board [][]= new int [Rows][columns];


        for (int row =0; row <=Rows-1;row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col <=columns-1; col ++)
            {
                board [row][col]= position;
                position--;
            }
             System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the output to print the board in a spiraled fashion, i.e:

```
100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91
81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90
80,79,78,77,76,75,74,73,72,71
```

However it is printing out like this,

```
100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91
90,89,88,87,86,85,84,83,82,81
80,79,78,77,76,75,74,73,72,71
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I know what you mean since I had the privilege of owning a snakes and ladders board as a child. But your description of *spiralling down* is awful. Describing a problem is an art: please try. Help us to help you.

Comment: The code you have posted is printing nothing but spaces. Please post the code that's actually giving the output you mention.

Comment: i want the numbers to zig-zag down,like a classic snakes and ladders game

Comment: @user2980885: much better. -1 becomes +1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q22099123;

public class PrintGrid
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int numRows = 10;
        int numColumns = 10;
        int numSpaces = numRows * numColumns;
        int[][] board = new int[numRows][numColumns];

        for (int space = 0; space < numSpaces; space++)
        {
            int row = space / numRows;
            int column = space % numColumns;
            if (row % 2 == 0)
            {
                board[row][column] = (numSpaces - space);
            }
            else
            {
                board[row][(numColumns - column) - 1] = (numSpaces - space);
            }
        }

        for (int[] row : board)
        {
            for (int col : row)
            {
                System.out.printf("%4d", col);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
 100  99  98  97  96  95  94  93  92  91
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  80  79  78  77  76  75  74  73  72  71
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  60  59  58  57  56  55  54  53  52  51
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  40  39  38  37  36  35  34  33  32  31
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  20  19  18  17  16  15  14  13  12  11
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

To be honest though, if you're making a snakes and ladders game, how the board is organized is really more of a display problem. It would probably make more sense to store the game spaces as an ascending 1D array (to make counting moves easier) and worry about handling the display of the board separately.

Comment: I'd agree with the display versus how-to-store-it-internally issue.  Displaying this is rather complicated, and therefore I'd recommend a pre-determining the display position, and setting it as an extra x/y coordinate in each `CellPosition` object.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to isolate the complexity into a *function*:

```
private static int getNumber(int row, int col)
{
    return row % 2 == 0 ? 100 - row * 10 - col : 91 - row * 10 + col;        
}
```

Where `getNumber(0, 0)` will return 100.

To generate your grid, use

```
for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row){
     for (int col = 0; col < 10; ++col){
         System.out.print(getNumber(row, col) + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row =0; row <=Rows-1;row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col <=columns-1; col ++)
        {
            if(row%2 == 1)
                 board[row][9-col] = position;
            else
                 board[row][col] = position

            position--;
        }
    }
```

I think you might be trying to structure it as above? You need to put in the `if` and `else` statements to make sure you add the values to the array backwards for every other array.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Jon Quarfoth, displaying the board should probably be handled separately from actually internally storing each cell-position. But since this is a relatively complicated way of displaying a sequence of positions, I'd recommend pre-determining the positions of each cell, and storing them in an x/y coordinate, in a `CellPosition` object.

```
public class CellPosition  {
   public final int rowIdx;   //X
   public final int colIdx;   //Y
   public final int positionNum;
   public class CellPosition(int rowIdx, int colIdx, int positionNum)  {
      this.rowIdx = rowIdx;
      this.colIdx = colIdx;
      this.positionNum = positionNum;
   }
}
```

However, I found the filling the two-dimensional array in a "spiraling fashion" to be quite a difficult-but-interesting problem. Here's my solution, which I solved by creating a "SpiralGridPositionIterator" (although it doesn't implement `Iterator`).

The main class:

```
import  java.util.NoSuchElementException;
/**
   <P>{@code java SpiralPositionXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class SpiralPositionXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      int rows = 10;
      int cols = 10;
      int[][] boardPositions = new int[rows][cols];

      SpiralGridPositionIterator gridPosItr = new SpiralGridPositionIterator(rows, cols);

      int positionNum = rows * cols;  //Start at max and descend

      //Fill the array
         while(gridPosItr.hasNext())  {
            gridPosItr.goToNext();
            //System.out.println("[" + gridPosItr.getRowIdx() + "," + gridPosItr.getColIdx() + "]=" + positionNum);
            boardPositions[gridPosItr.getRowIdx()][gridPosItr.getColIdx()] = positionNum--;
         }

      //Display
         for(int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rows; rowIdx++)  {
            for(int colIdx = 0; colIdx < cols; colIdx++)  {
               System.out.print(boardPositions[rowIdx][colIdx] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
         }
   }
}
```

The iterator:

```
class SpiralGridPositionIterator  {
//config
   public final int rows;
   public final int cols;
//state
   private int rowIdx;
   private int colIdx;
   private boolean isColIdxAsc;
//internal
   private final int colsMinus1;
   private final int rowsMinus1;

   public SpiralGridPositionIterator(int rows, int cols)  {
      this.rows = rows;
      this.cols = cols;

      colIdx = -1;  //MUST initialize to -1  (See "First time is a special case")
      rowIdx = 0;

      isColIdxAsc = true;
      colsMinus1 = cols - 1;
      rowsMinus1 = rows - 1;
   }
   public boolean hasNext()  {
      if(getRowIdx() < rowsMinus1)  {
         return  true;
      }
      return  (isColIdxAsc
            ?  getColIdx() < colsMinus1
            :  getColIdx() > 0);
   }
   public void goToNext()  {
      if(colIdx == -1)  {
         //First time is a special case.  (See "MUST initialize to -1")
         colIdx = 0;
         rowIdx = 0;
         return;
      }
      if(!hasNext())  {
         throw  new NoSuchElementException();
      }

      if(isColIdxAsc)  {
         if(getColIdx() < colsMinus1)  {
            colIdx++;
         }  else  {

            //In last column
            isColIdxAsc = !isColIdxAsc;
            rowIdx++;
         }

      //ELSE: Descending
      }  else if(getColIdx() > 0) {
         colIdx--;

      }  else  {

         //In first column
         isColIdxAsc = !isColIdxAsc;
         rowIdx++;
      }
   }
   public int getRowIdx()  {
      return  rowIdx;
   }
   public int getColIdx()  {
      return  colIdx;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java SpiralPositionXmpl
100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```